# Why is echo of php breaking my script?

Tags: javascript, php

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            var php_var = '<?php echo addslashes($dealpromo); ?>';

            var headerel = document.getElementsByClassName('content-header')[0];
            alert(headerel);
            headerel.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = php_var;
            </script>";
```

if I remove

```
var php_var = '<?php echo addslashes($dealpromo); ?>';
```

then the alert happens, if I leave it in, I don't get the alert, and obviously don't get my element to have the php_var like I want...

Comment: Why would you echo a script at all, put that script in a .js file and echo the URL in the .php file as an attribute or whatever.

Comment: how do I get the php variables to the js file?

Comment: Uhm, `getAttribute` or datasets comes to mind ?

Comment: honestly, no - I'm not familiar with what your saying...

Comment: If at all possible, put HTML, javascript and CSS in separate files, and don't echo entire scripts from PHP. In your case, the entire script is just nonsense, as you could have echoed the PHP data straight into the HTML of the H2 tag instead of using javascript.

Comment: How do I do this with just php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I think you should concatenate the `addslashes($dealpromo);` instead of echoing it (since you're already doing an echo).

```
var php_var = '" . addslashes( $dealpromo ) . "';
```

Answer (score 3):

probably you're looking for:

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        var php_var = '" . addslashes($dealpromo) . "';
        var headerel = document.getElementsByClassName('content-header')[0];
        alert(headerel);
        headerel.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = php_var;
        </script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice and sleek and not so popular way to do it is using the Print(); function.

However,it is better to use it for "simple values" like a plain variables:

```
    var MyJSStringVar = "<?php Print($MyPHPStringVar); ?>";
    var MyJSNumVar = <?php Print($MyPHPNumVar); ?>;
```